# c++ library/sample to transport voice and video over TCP/IP

Tags: c++, video, tcp, voice

Can someone point me some c++ samples or some c++ librarys that can transport video and voice over a LAN network.

My objective is to activate a web cam in another pc and receive in my pc the video and voice of the another pc (this can be only one way or in both ways pc to pc call, but i only need one way for now, only see and hear not to interact).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If working on Windows try out the [NetMeeting Resource Kit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc767134.aspx). It probably limits playing your videos with Windows Media Player only.

Answer (score 0):

VNC and all its variants should be able to do it.

[TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) Free.

[Another VNC Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/securevncviewer.aspx)

I can't locate a source code link right now, but if you search with vigor it should be revealed.

WebEx's entire business was built on a forked version of VNC. Fun.